# Map color collision problem

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, maps, wpf

Hello i'm doing a game in WPF, 2D version (top view)

I have the map and i'm trying to check for color collision in pixel each time the timer is activated

Well...with 1 object it works fine but with more objects at same time it just slow down the process

This is my code every time the dispatchertimer activates and i loop to check for collision on every object

```
CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(source, new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1));
int px = 1 * (source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
byte[] pixels = new byte[px * 1];
cb.CopyPixels(pixels, px, 0);
Color c = Color.FromArgb(pixels[3], pixels[2], pixels[1], pixels[0]);
if (c.R == 255 && c.B == 255 && c.G == 255) {
   pixels = null;
   return true;
}
```

Any help to simplify the process? I really want to do it in WPF

PS: The map is 1018x731

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem here is that you continuously allocate new memory. Instead of creating small buffers for each pixel you want to read, why not create a buffer from all the image pixels and the read directly from there?

Here's how I would modify your code. Disclaimer: I've never used WPF before, so take this with a grain of salt. I don't know how the pixel data is ordered in the array etc.

```
// -- Don't do this inside the loop, but somewhere else 
// and keep a pointer to the pixels array
// read the entire image into a buffer
CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(source, new Int32Rect(0, 0, 1018, 731));
int px = 1018 * 731 * (source.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
byte[] pixels = new byte[px];
cb.CopyPixels(pixels, px, 0);

// -- do this inside your loop
// calculate the offset into the array
int offset = (y * 1018 + x) * 4;
Color c = Color.FromArgb(
    pixels[offset + 3], pixels[offset + 2], pixels[offset + 1], pixels[offset]);

if (c.R == 255 && c.B == 255 && c.G == 255) {
   pixels = null;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.
The only problem is that the offset throws a exception but i will take care of it, apart of that is awesome :)

Well i have one other question, Is appropriate to loop for 51 items and check the collision for each one? Is there any alternative? Because I already did the dumb test and the application don't move :P

Well, i'm just new at game development (graphical interface)

Comment: @GameDev checking 51 items per update should not be a problem. But that really depends on what your check *actually does*... Just implement it and if it's slow, then profile it to find the problem. That's all the advice I can give you.

Comment: should the problem be wpf and to not be a good plataform to develop such a game or it's programming problems like above?